# Using AsyncMock with context manager to assert await was called (python)

Tags: python, python-asyncio, python-unittest, python-unittest.mock

I am new to using asyncio in Python and I'm having trouble figuring out how to write a test which uses python-websockets (and asyncio). I want to have a client which connects to a websocket and sends a message once connected

Here is my client class:

```
 
import json
import websockets


class Client:

    def __init__(self, interval):
        self.interval = interval

    async def connect(self):
        async with websockets.connect("wss://test.com", ping_interval=self.interval) as websocket:
            await self._send_message(websocket)

    async def _send_message(self, websocket):
        message = {"messageId": "499"}
        await websocket.send(json.dumps(message))
```

and here is my test

```
import json
import unittest
from unittest.mock import AsyncMock, patch
from client import Client


class ConnectionTest(unittest.IsolatedAsyncioTestCase):
    async def test_message_is_sent(self):
        websocket_client = Client(interval=4)
        
        mock_websocket = AsyncMock()

        with patch("client.websockets.connect", return_value=mock_websocket):
            await websocket_client.connect()
            message = {"messageId": "499"}
            mock_websocket.send.assert_awaited_once_with(json.dumps(message))
```

I'm getting the error:

`E AssertionError: Expected send to have been awaited once. Awaited 0 times.`

Because this context manager is being replaced with an AsyncMock() I'd assume that I'd be able to see that `send` was called with await, and then be able to assert on it.

Am I misunderstanding how this is supposed to be used?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are patching wrong.

Try to patch `websockets.connect` instead of `client.websockets.connect`:

```
with patch("websockets.connect", return_value=mock_websocket):
```